# Why my discord.js v14 bot saying "The application did not respond" but the command work?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, channel

Ty for reading me !

I have a bot using discord.js, and I am trying to get it to work in discord.js V14.

I had no problem but except one thing, the channel.send().

Here is my command:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ApplicationCommandType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'regles',
    description: "Affiche les règles du serveur Mobile Rush.",
    type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
    cooldown: 3000,
    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder() // création de l'embed
            .setColor(`#FCFF22`) // ou .setColor(`#0099ff`)
            .setTitle(`:scroll: Règlement du serveur :scroll:`)

            .setDescription(`Voici le règlement du serveur, veuillez le prendre en compte et l'intégrer à votre expérience sur le discord.\n \n`
            +`:page_with_curl: 1 - Traiter tout le monde avec respect : Aucun harcèlement, troll/taunt virulent, sexisme, racisme ou discours de haine ne sera toléré.\n \n`
            +`:page_with_curl: 2 - Pas de contenu violent, obscène ou NSFW qu'il s'agisse d'un texte, image ou lien mettant en scène de la nudité, du sexe, de violence ou un quelconque contenu dérangeant.\n \n`
            +`:page_with_curl: 3 - Pas de spam dans les channels.\n \n`
            +`:page_with_curl: 4 - Les publicités en tout genre ne sont pas autorisées sur le serveur.\n \n`
            +`:page_with_curl: 5 - Veuillez utiliser les bons salons textuels pour ne pas voir vos messages supprimés par les modérateurs.\n \n`
            +`*En cas de non respect des règles, <@817169336074371072> appliquera des sanctions plus ou moins lourdes.*`);

        const channel = await client.channels.cache.get('818097356725157900');//channel test-bot
        channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        
    }
};
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvbQ1.png)

The command work good, my embed go to the right channel, but i got this error each time when i use channel.send, but not when i use interaction.reply.

I try with a new bot code that I get on discord.js doc, I try with a code the a guy do, but always the same thing ..
I search on internet, I didn't find something with that.

I hope someone can help me!

[How can i get my discord.js v14 bot to stop saying "The application did not respond" if the slash command works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75043833/how-can-i-get-my-discord-js-v14-bot-to-stop-saying-the-application-did-not-resp)
Someone here have the same error, but he resolve it with and interaction.reply, but i can't do that for go to another channel

Comment: Your last edit should be a response. A question should not contain an answer. If you found a solution, you can post it as an answer below. Oh, I can see that you already deleted your answer, you can undelete that :)

Comment: Oh sorry it's first time i use stackoverflow, ty i move my answer !

Answer (score 2):

Discord Interactions don't consider themselves responded to unless you use the inbuilt reply function, simply replace `channel.send` with
`interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })`

(You can reply a dummy message, like "Complete!" etc, then send the embed to the channel you want to.)

Comment: I can do a thing like that : 
        interaction.reply('This message is send');
        channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

That not really what i want, but i don't have error with, i wait if someone have another solution but if not i will use that, ty !

Comment: There isn't another solution, discord will always mark an interaction as not responded to unless you defer a reply and then edit it or simply reply to it.

Only way to do that without without replying at all is by using message commands.

Comment: Message commands ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const channel = await client.channels.cache.get('818097356725157900');
interaction.reply('This message is send');
await interaction.deleteReply();
channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

I just going to do that, I can also do `interaction.reply` ephemeral, ty Dan for your response !